# How does sonar:sonar work?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, bamboo, sonarqube-scan

We want to use SonarQube with some CI tool in our project. Sonar Server url is configured in main *pom.xml*.

There are several team memebers in the project. So what happen when one team member executes **sonar:sonar** locally with his local changes, then another team member executes **sonar:sonar** with his local changes, and then someone executes **sonar:sonar** from CI tool (it is configured to analyse source code in Git repository)?

Will SonarQube display issues related team members local changes? What if there are differences between team members local source code and source code in Git repository?

Comment: Its best to keep the keep sonarqube setting in a different file sonar.properties than pom.xml. And don't include it as part of your Source Management which is shared among developers. Finally place the file in the directory on the system where CI is running the build and configure it appropriately.

Comment: @Nobody Keeping build configuration separate from the codebase is a royal headache, and CI systems are moving to storing the metadata inside it. (Looking at you, Jenkins.)

Comment: @chrylis i meant keep the configuration out of pom file. and not out of source management. CI can pick anything which is part of source management and can be downloaded. Ya I know Jenkins.. Jenkins has something called pipelines and execute from batch.. So its about how you setup Jenkins. Keeping configuration separately will prevent accidently report upload to sonar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sonar:sonar` executes analysis and sends the results to the server - assuming you're running it with the token of an account that has the appropriate privileges.

Developers *should not* be running this type of analysis locally to check their changes. Instead, they should be using [SonarLint](http://sonarlint.org) and perhaps [pull request analysis](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) (depending on your infrastructure).

(**EDIT:** Pull request analysis has been deprecated and replaced by a fuller-featured [Branch analysis](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/)($).)

To expand a little on why developers shouldn't be using `sonar:sonar` locally: it updates the central server in a last-saved-wins manner. So if you've edited A.java and analyzed it locally before commit, and I've renamed A.java to B.java and done a similar pre-commit local analysis... what's visible on the SonarQube server? Depends on who saved/analyzed last.

Instead, `sonar:sonar` should be run only from your CI tool on the checked-in code that's already *visible to the whole team*.

Comment: If it is first build, when new project will be created in SonarQube? After executing _sonar:sonar_ Sonar Maven Plugin get rules from SonarQube Server, SonarQube Server creates new project, Sonar Maven Plugin executes analysis and sends the results to the server? Did I describe right sequence?

Comment: I believe project creation happens after the analysis report is submitted to the server.

Comment: After executing sonar:sonar in maven. Sonar given report of code duplication in java file. Like "1 duplicated blocks of code must be removed". So i reviewed my code no where code is duplicated in java file except only few method are duplicated on different object. In this senior we can able remove or rename something like that on duplicated methods. Is there any to resolve this type of problem in sonar. Or is there an exclusion to add in pom.xml file ???

Comment: Pls have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027391/does-maven-sonarqube-plugin-reads-failsafe-reports

Answer (score 2):

As you said that sonar server url is cofigured in mail pom.xml and your team member's run sonar:sonar command at there local machine. But because of all referring to the same server url. So all changes will reflect for a common project. If you want to see then difference separately for each team member. then either you need to update the project name distinct from each other. Other wise you will see latest one there.

Sonar gives you difference in graphical manner. as well as you can compare two build too.

Second If user has administrator grant only then they can update sonar server else not.